# Google homepage's drop shadow search box - Right or Wrong?

Tags: website-design

Google has decided to make the search box have drop shadow shading on the UK site...

[image: Google Homepage - UK]

However the "Google Search" and "I'm Feeling Lucky" buttons are flat (without shading).

It just looks "wrong"  (like an Escher drawing)

How could the UX of Google's home page be improved ? (all 3D ? no 3D ??)

Comment: Voting to close as this is mainly a matter of opinion and more about visual design than UX as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search input is what Material design calls a [Persistent Search](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/search.html#search-in-app-search):

> **Persistent search**
>
> Use persistent search when search is the primary focus of your app.

So it has a [shadow elevation](https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/elevation-shadows.html#elevation-shadows-elevation-android) corresponding to a search box:

[image]

The buttons are not actually flat buttons, they have a border (1px solid #f2f2f2), background and they raise on hover. However they are not following Material design guidelines about Raised buttons neither.

> Raised buttons have a default elevation of 2dp.

Right or Wrong?

I'm quite sure they know what they are doing **so probably Right for their goals** which might be to encourage the recognition of the search input.

Answer (score 2):

According to Google, it's OK by their own guidelines. Just go to https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/elevation-shadows.html#elevation-shadows-shadows and under the **Component** **Reference** title you'll find the components that CAN use elevation and shadows, including the following one:

[image]

So as you can see, by Google standards is correct. However, if you want to do it in your own site, I'd suggest you test this a lot. Google only has a logo, the search box and the buttons, while most sites will have a lot of other elements

Answer (score 1):

The background is white so the drop shadow works to highlight the search box in a minimal way. Good.

Comment: Do you have any references to Google's material design to back this up?

Comment: @BDD https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/elevation-shadows.html#elevation-shadows-shadows

Comment: "Shadows provide important visual cues about objects’ depth and directional movement. **They are the only visual cue indicating the amount of separation between surfaces.**"

Answer (score 0):

Like anything subjective, the UX can always be enhanced, but I don't think that change here is necessary for "improvement." Since Google has the advantage of having written the book on Material Design, they're actually following their own rules consistently regarding [Shadows and Shading](https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/elevation-shadows.html#elevation-shadows-shadows). The shadow does the job of calling out which component is the most important on the page, and everything else recedes, including (as you point out) the brand itself. Good question!